# QEMU device tree (DTS/DTB) based device spotting

Tags: fpga, qemu, device-tree

Can QEMU automatically add devices from device tree to machine?

I know that it probably is not possible in mainline QEMU just by looking at implementation https://github.com/qemu/qemu/blob/master/hw/arm/virt.c#L1242 etc...
But it seems to me as "must have feature" for FPGA developers. I guess that someone already had to implement it.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more what you mean by "add devices from device tree to machine"?

Comment: I was thinking if there is a machine definition which loads it's devices definitions and configuration from the dts.

Comment: Some links for this topic: [1](https://elinux.org/CELF_Project_Proposal/Add_Device_Tree_emulation_support_to_QEMU) [2](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/qemu-linaro/+spec/qemu-pass-in-device-tree)

Comment: Link 2 is passing of DTS to kernel which is something different. Link 1 is very close, from machine definition it generates device tree which is awesome feature. I was searching for opposite thing from DTS generate machine (= based quemu read before start the DTS as the linux will and adds devices to machine). However this would require that any QEMU "device" has known compatibility string and every configuration is written in DTS and can be added to machine.